# How to calculate average value of an interval given subinterval average values?

Tags: calculus, average

I have a problem where it gives us average value over 3 sub intervals that are contained within an entire interval. To find the average value of the entire interval is it possible to just add the average values of the 3 sub intervals or is that not right? For example the average value is as follows for the intervals: (0,3)= 2 and (3,4)=2 would (0,4)=4? I have tried adding them together and multiplying by 1/b-a of the entire interval. I'm not sure if that works.

Comment: You cannot say anything about the average value until you have a definition of "average value over an interval". What definition are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the average value of a function f  on an interval $[a,b]$ you have to compute $$ F(b)-F(a)\over b-a$$ Where $F’(x)=f(x)$  
 So if you want to compute the average from $[a,b]$ : you can’t just add individual averages  that is avg[a,c]+avg[c,b] because if you use the formula you will see it does not work.